# table LaTeX on the right the table does not close

Tags: tables

i have problem with table LaTeX,on the right the table does not close

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath, array}
\usepackage{shapepar, pifont, color, enumerate}
\usepackage{multirow}
\voffset-30mm
\hoffset-15mm
\textwidth175mm
\textheight260mm

\begin{document}       
 \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
        $x$ & $\left(-\infty;{0}\right)$  & $\left(0\right)$ & $\left(0;\frac{{4}}{3}\right)$ & $\frac{{4}}{3}$ & $\Big(\frac{{4}}{3};{\frac{8}{3}}\Big]$ & ${\frac{8}{3}}$  &   $\left(\frac{{8}}{3};+\infty\right)$ \\
    \hline
        $f'(x)$ & $-$ & $0$ & $+$ & $+$ & $0$ & $-$ & $-$  \\
    \hline
        $f''(x)$ & $+$ & 0 & {$-$}& {$-$} & 0 & $+$ & $+$  \\
    \hline
        {$f(x)$} & {$\searrow$} & $f_{max}=$  &\multicolumn{2}{c|} {\multirow{2}{*}{$\nearrow$}} & $f_{min}=$ & \multicolumn{2}{c|} {\multirow{2}{*}{$\searrow$}} \\
        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\phantom{,}} & ${\frac{121}{81}}$ & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\phantom{,}} &  ${-\frac{5}{3}}$ \\
    \cline{2-8}
        &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{{\Large $\smile$}}}  &Точка перегиба& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{{\Large $\frown$}}} \\
     & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\phantom{,}}      & \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular} \\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: in rows with missing vertical lines you not have all ampersands. since code of the your table is very difficult to understand, please find yourself, where is missing or reduce your mwe just this table and remove all what is not relevant to this table. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: I tried to compile it and it works just fine. Simply I don't have the math but Cyrillic text.

Comment: I reduced my code

Comment: *Off-topic:* It is usually a bad Idea to change `\hoffset` and `\voffset` manually. `\textwidth` and `\textheight` should be changed with the `geometry` package...

Comment: Excuse me, please, my English-level A2 and I do not understand you well), could you please correct my code? Please, I will be very grateful to you

Answer (score 2):

Why do you declare 11 columns when you use 8? I simplified you code to use the `array` environment, replaced `\multirow` with `\makecell`, which allows for line breaks in standard cells and added some vertical padding to the cells.

Unrelated: your way of specifying layout parameters isn' correct (the space for margin notes overflows outside the paper sheet). You should use  the `geometry` package, which is more intuitive.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, array}
\usepackage{ makecell, bigstrut}
\voffset-30mm
\hoffset-15mm
\textwidth175mm
\textheight260mm

\begin{document}

\[ \setcellgapes{4pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{array}[t]{|*{8}{c|}}
    \hline
        x & (-\infty;{0} ) & (0 ) & \bigl(0;\frac{4}{3}\bigr) & \frac{4}{3} & \bigl(\frac{4}{3};{\frac{8}{3}}\bigr] & \frac{8}{3} & \bigl(\frac{{8}}{3};+\infty\bigr) \\
    \hline
        f'(x) & - & 0 & + & + & 0 & - & - \\
    \hline
        f''(x) & + & 0 & {-}& {-} & 0 & + & + \\
    \hline
        {f(x)} & {\searrow} &\makecell{f_\text{max}=\\ \frac{121}{81}} &\multicolumn{2}{c|} {\nearrow} & \makecell{f_\text{min}= \\ -\frac{5}{3}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|} {\searrow} \\
    \cline{2-8}
        &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\text{\Large $ \smile $}} & \bigstrut[t]\text{Точка перегиба}& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\text{\Large $ \frown $}} \\
    \hline
    \end{array} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

with use of the packages `makecell` and `tabularx`, page layout determined by the package `geometry`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,
            nccmath} % for midsize fraction \mfrac{}{}. it also call amsmath
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%


\begin{document}

\begingroup
\centering
\setcellgapes{4pt}\makegapedcells
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{|>{\centering\arraybackslash $}l<{$}|
                            *{7}{>{\centering\arraybackslash $}X<{$}|}}
    \hline
        x & (-\infty;{0} ) & (0 ) & \Bigl(0;\mfrac{4}{3}\Bigr) & \mfrac{4}{3} & \Bigl(\mfrac{4}{3};{\mfrac{8}{3}}\Bigr] & \mfrac{8}{3} & \Bigl(\mfrac{{8}}{3};+\infty\Bigr) \\
    \hline
        f'(x) & - & 0 & + & + & 0 & - & - \\
    \hline
        f''(x) & + & 0 & {-}& {-} & 0 & + & + \\
    \hline
        {f(x)} & {\searrow} &\makecell{f_\text{max}=\mfrac{121}{81}} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\nearrow$}
        & \makecell{f_\text{min}=-\mfrac{5}{3}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|} {$\searrow$} \\
    \cline{2-8}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\text{\Large $\smile $}}
        & \makecell{\text{Точка}\\ \text{перегиба}}
        & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\text{\Large $\frown $}} \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```